# Geopoint function distance not working in FieldExpression

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search

I am using Google App Engine and storing geopoints in searchable document index.  When I search for locations using distance function for example "**distance**(myGeoPoint, geopoint(35.2, 40.5)) > 100" search returns expected documents.  In returned results, I want to find out distance of each of myGeoPoint from passed in geopoint, so I added a "distance" FieldExpression in QueryOptions but looks like the field expression doesn't get evaluated and search returns the field as HTML with empty value.  But to ensure I am building FieldExpression correctly, I tried by replacing the expression with some other expression, for example (count(someOtherField)) and it works and returns correct data.  So looks like something is wrong with my usage of distance function.  Does anybody know what is wrong with my usage of distance function in FieldExpression? It is supposed to work, correct?  Or distance functions are not supported with FieldExpressions?

Alternatively, is there any other way to get distance between point of interest to all locations matching search query?

My sample code:

```
    // use search api
    IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName(
            "com.mycompany").build();
    Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService()
            .getIndex(indexSpec);
    QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder()
            .setLimit(100)
            .setFieldsToReturn("myGeoPoint")
            .addExpressionToReturn(FieldExpression.newBuilder()
                    .setName("calculatedDistance")
                    .setExpression("distance(myGeoPoint, geopoint(37.738767, -122.424037))"))
            .build();
    Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build("distance(myGeoPoint, geopoint(37.738767, -122.424037)) < 10000");

    Results<ScoredDocument> results = null;
    try {
        results = index.search(query);
        for (ScoredDocument document : results) {
            List<Field> expressions = document.getExpressions();
            for (Field e : expressions) {
                System.out.println("expression=" + e);  
            }
        }
    } catch (SearchException e) {
        if (StatusCode.TRANSIENT_ERROR.equals(
                e.getOperationResult().getCode())) {
            results = index.search(query);                
        }
    }
```

This is what I see in output (instead of HTML, I am expecting calculatedDistance as number with valid numeric value):

expression=Field(name=calculatedDistance, value=, type=HTML)

Comment: I have done this (returned distance values as an expression) and it worked just fine. I wrote a PHP wrapper library to do it here https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-search#distance-from - but I'll try and dig out the effective query it generates.

Comment: So I checked the query and it seems identical to yours on first look! Maybe try without the return field list?

Comment: Tried it without specifying return field list, but same incorrect HTML output.  I am testing this in dev environment as I don't see any limitation called out by Google  [link] (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/devserver).  Is this distance function call in FieldExpression supposed to work only in production app engine?